# MySql.Data.MySqlClient can't connect after NET framework update

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have a Windows service running without any problems on Windows Server 2003 non-stop for more than one month.

But on 11.10.2013 1:00 UTC was update of NET framework automaticaly instaled on server. Windows shutdown services including mine before update. And after update services was started again, but my service wasn't able to connect to mysql server in the startup to obtain data.

I'm using this code:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WatchDog.Properties.Settings.Mysql"].ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
```

Config file with ConnectionString wasn't changed since instalation (one month ago). I have verify it, and its correct

And i got this message in Event viewer: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" Unfortunetly I don't have stack trace logged, but working on geting it.

I have library Mysql.Data copied localy with my program.

But in the same time PHP part of  program connects to same mysql server, database with same user without any problems. After uninstaling updates (I know not very good thing from view of security) program was working smothly again.

And what's more same program works on my Windows 7 notebook without problems.

Do you have any idea what is causiong this realy strange behaviour?

Comment: Which version of MySql.Data.dll do you have installed? Have you tried to update to the lastest one?

Comment: Currently 6.6.5.0, I'll update it.

Comment: But even if update of MySql.Data.dll will help, it's just temporary solution until next update of NET framework will be realesed. 
Do know any better and mainly long term maintence-free solution to this problem?